# S3 Upload Issue

Tags: fine-uploader

I am trying to upload a file on S3. I have been verified everything couple of times and all looks correct to me, but whenever I am trying to upload file, getting error message saying

 
responseText = 

`InvalidArgument
POST requires exactly one file upload per request.
0
file
3670E4EE52B3BCD5
b3rOF/9WJHymo1ZENIOlrct/ZusAJ50AnSIP0df3K3+DdEcAFolJDx8qU6DH2N1l`

Can someone please help me to findout what I am doing wrong here?

```
    <div id="s3-fileuploader" class="dropArea"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

        //block and unblock UIbased on endpoint url
        function setUI(){
            j$('div.dropArea').unblock();
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#s3-fileuploader').fineUploader({

                request: {
                    endpoint: "https://{!bucketname}.s3.amazonaws.com",
                    accessKey: "{!key}"
                },
                signature: {

                    //always included
                    "expiration": "{!expireStr}",

                    signature : "{!signedPolicy}",
                    policy: "{!policy}",

                    "conditions":
                    [
                        //always included
                        {"acl": "public-read"},

                        //always included
                        {"bucket": "{!bucketname}"},

                        //not included in IE9 and older or Android 2.3.x and older
                        {"Content-Type": "{!ContentType}"},

                        //always included
                        {"key": "{!key}"},

                        //always included
                        {"x-amz-meta-qqfilename": "{!URLENCODE('test.jpg')}"},
                    ]
                },
                cors: {
                    expected: true, //all requests are expected to be cross-domain requests
                    sendCredentials: false, //if you want cookies to be sent along with the request
                    allowXdr: true
                },

                autoUpload: true,
                multiple:false,
                debug: true,

                text: {
                    uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white">Select Files</i> '
                },     
                uploadSuccess: {
                    endpoint: "{!redirectURL}"
                }
            }).on('submit',function(event,id,name){

                //set endpoint
                console.log('https://{!bucketname}.s3.amazonaws.com');
                $(this).fineUploader('setEndpoint','https://{!bucketname}.s3.amazonaws.com');

            });
            setUI();
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature option is supposed to include information about your signature server.  Instead you are apparently attaching an (invalid) policy document to this option.  Furthermore, you do not create the police document, Fine Uploader creates it for you and passes it to your signature server for signing.

Also you should be using the fineUploaderS3 jquery plugin for this.

It looks like you have not read the documentation that describes how Fine Uploader S3 works.  I suggest starting with the guides on the home page of http://docs.fineuploader.com.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I am doing the same thing with native HTML form, everything works fine and file in being uploaded to S3 perfectly. So I am pretty sure about the accuracy of params. I am trying this with Salesforce.  When I am doing this with fineUploader, I am getting error. Does fineUploader support Salesforce?

Comment: I saw console and it says:

------WebKitFormBoundarySeVUAfRfUe5pSOey
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qquuid"

c063f3b6-101e-4421-be23-2ceca7db051a
------WebKitFormBoundarySeVUAfRfUe5pSOey
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqtotalfilesize"

8858
------WebKitFormBoundarySeVUAfRfUe5pSOey
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfile"; filename="11112.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundarySeVUAfRfUe5pSOey--

Comment: Again, you will need to start by reading the Fine Uploader S3 documentation.  There are a number of issues with your code.  If you want to upload directly to S3 Fine Uploader S3 can do that for you, but you are not configuring it correctly at all and appear to be unaware of how it works.  After reading the documentation and looking at some of the sample code, you should be on the right path.